# DatePicker for Angular 8 Application

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular8

Which is the Best Date Picker compatible with Angular 8 Application.

Right now i am using `ngbDatepicker`, but we dont have enough options in it to control dates and change format is complex, i am looking for a datepicker similar to `mydatepicker`(this plugin is not supporting) for Angular 8 Application

DatePicker compatible with Angular 8 Application.

- Should have features to change date Format.
- Should control date Like disable future dates.
- Should support all type of forms; like formControlName and ngModel's

Comment: The Angular-Material Datepicker can everthing you want. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: ngbDatePicker fit with all your requirements too -check the last version, to change format it's not complex, just use locate-

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using this one [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)?
This one is optimized for Angular and is commonly used UI Library. Also supports all types of forms you've mention above.